# I don't receive the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED in the Emulator

Tags: android, service, bootcompleted

I'm French sorry for my English. I'm trying to develop an autoboot service that runs in the background and catches SMS. After a lot of research, I wasn't able to solve my problem.

I can't run the service after the boot and I don't receive the log

```
 Log.v("LTM","MyReceiver.onReceive: "+intent.getAction());
```

that should to be printed by the BootReceiver. (CF Code below)

I verified the AndroidManifest, tested different code, and nothing works right. I use Eclipse and test the code with the Android Virtual Devices, so maybe the problem comes from the Emulator and I tested with a real device but it didn't start too.

You can find the code below. Thank you for your help.

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.smsmanager"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="8"
      android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

    <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <service android:enabled="true" android:label="ServiceGUI"     android:name="com.smsmanager.MainService"/>

        <receiver android:enabled="true"         android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" android:name=".MyReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver class="com.smsmanager.SMSReceiver" android:name="com.smsmanager.SMSReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="100">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Main:**

```
package com.smsmanager;

import com.smsmanager.SMSReceiver;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainService extends Service {
    SMSReceiver rec;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.v("LTM", "Demarrage du service");
        rec=new SMSReceiver();
        Log.v("LTM", "Retour dans le service");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

**Receiver:**

```
package com.smsmanager;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("LTM","MyReceiver.onReceive: "+intent.getAction());
    Intent intent1=new Intent(ctx,MainService.class);
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    ctx.startService(intent1);

}

}
```

Comment: What android version of emulator that you're using? And real device too?

Comment: This is the AVD details :
CPU/ABI : ARM (armeabi-v7a)
Target : Android 4.1.2 (API level16)
device name : Nexus 4